# Property value is not refreshing on Template when its Non-Primitive type

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to update value of property in Parent Component which is pass in Child component. But after update value is reflecting in child component'c class (.js) but not in view (.html)

Is it possible to update the same value in view as well which is working in case of primitive type.

Here is the code:

parent.html

```
<template>
parent data : {dta.key}
<lightning-button onclick={updateValue} label="Update Data"></lightning-button>
<c-childcomp dta={dta} ></c-childcomp>
```

parent.js

```
@track
dta = {key:"value"};
updateValue() {
    this.dta.key = 'Mekyush';
}
```

childcomp.html

```
<template>
child Data : {dta.key} 
<lightning-button onclick={checkValue} label="checkval"></lightning-button>
```

childcomp.js

```
@api dta;
connectedCallback() {
    console.log(this.dta);
}
checkValue() {
    console.log(this.dta);
}
```

Comment: I set up a quick sample using your code in the LWC playground and I'm seeing the correct value in both the view and the output to the console. Is this all of code that makes up your components? Or could there be something else possibly interfering?

Comment: @JohnTowers I'm encountering this as well. My code is here: https://pastebin.com/JUmVwT3A . The parent component's binding is updated when the button is pressed, but the child component's is not.

Comment: @JohnTowers yes value is updating in Class file, you will get updated value in method `checkValue` of child component but value is not reflected in view `child Data : {dta.key}`. Please share me Playground link

Comment: Here is my code in the playground. It seems to work there, but does NOT work in an org. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/nsmJnkgVl/1/edit

Comment: @Jeff I did some more testing (I put the results [here](https://github.com/jtowers/LWCReactivePropertyBehavior) if you're interested) and the behavior in an org seems inconsistent. I can get the template to rerender under some circumstances, though. From what I read in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_props_reactive_data_types), it sounds like the template should rerender since the properties on an reactive object are tracked. This seems like a bug - or at least a very confusing behavior that should be made more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug but i find the workaround.

you have to add one dummy variable in parent and update everytime when you are updating map. also pass dummy variable in child and place in template and hide it.

Please refer [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/q8rtcVIBf/16/edit)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's a bug to not updating the latest data in real-time. The same happened to me.

You can use this method where you can directly call a child component method which sets data for you to show on the child component. the method should be prepended with @api.for example in our case on the child component

```
@api checkValue(value) {
    this.dta.key = value; 
}
```

and then you can pass data from a parent component method (updatedValue) when you call this method, like below

```
updateValue() {
    this.dta.key = 'Sachin';
    this.template.querySelector('c-child').checkValue(this.dta.key);
}
```

you can refer to this link [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/T3AK9Pa4T/49/edit).

please feel free to contact for more information.